# Using tikzmark in leaflet

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzmark, leaflet

There seems to be some problems when using tikzmark (or similar) in a leaflet document. I'm guessing this has to do with the strange positioning leaflet performs.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{leaflet}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
This is a \pgfmark{A}minimal test\pgfmark{B}.

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw (pic cs:A) edge[bend right] (pic cs:B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you change the documentclass to `article` it works as expected (drawing a curve from under the `m` to under the `t`). However in a leaflet it doesn't draw anything in the picture.

Is there any way to get tikzmark to work within a leaflet document? (I have already tried messing around with `\AddToBackground`, both starred and not)

Comment: you could open an issue at https://github.com/rolfn/leaflet/issues. Perhaps the author has an idea.